# Google Play Services 9.2.0 missing classes

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-support-library

After an update to Google Play Services 9.2.0 of 28th, June, there are some missing classes that prevent working projects from compiling:

> Error:(24, 35) error: package com.google.android.gms.maps does not
>   exist

The same about Google Places, so if you updated to google play services 9.2.0, your project probably won't compile.

Downgrading to 9.0.2 solves the problem:

> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'

Does anyone know how to fix the issue in version 9.2.0?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add the maps library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
```

and the places library:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

`play-services-location` 9.0.2 depends on and automatically brings into your project `play-services-maps` and `play-services-places`, have a look at `play-services-location-9.0.2.pom`. Version 9.2.0 doesn't do that anymore so it is up to you to add it as your project dependency.

For other missing classes you can check here to find the right package (see **Table 1** *Individual APIs and corresponding build.gradle descriptions*): https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: In my case, the specific dependency is already in the `build.gradle` file but that still doesn't work. any other ideas? (tried upgrading the build tools and compileSDK to 24 as well)

Comment: which are the missing classes? maybe you need to add the places library "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0" (also try to clean your project)

Comment: `SupportMapFragment`, `CameraUpdate` and others. nothing to do with places. the maps dependency should be sufficient. that's why i'm puzzled...

Comment: tried `clean`, `rebuild`, restarted Android Studio. nothing works

Comment: that's strange... if i add maps library to empty project i can see them.. check that you have the right import (import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;)

Comment: Yes. the correct import is there. I worked with the maps dependency with version 9.0.2 with no problem so no code change should be required. Must be something with the project/module configuration

Comment: So i finally figured it out. can't say why it happened but since the dependency was in a library module (with the Activity that requires that) it failed to find the library jar. When looking in the project .idea/libraries folder in the `play_services_maps_9_2_0.xml` file, it referred to the build folder of the app module that uses that library. since the app module was not built yet, the jar was not in the expected place. I manually copied the jar to the app module build library and than the classes were found.

Comment: @Bronx Your solution helped me. I had `location` and `maps` in my gradle which used to work fine. After updating it could never find google places. So I added places as well now and it works.

Answer (score 0):

add
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'

btw, a good starting point to check is, create a new maps project at current updated android studio (and libs) and have a look whats different

Comment: The 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0' dependency, contains all Google Play Services packages, adding a lot of unneedded dependencies to the project