# Google Play Location Services 9.2.0 missing Google attribution Android resource

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, location-services

I was trying to upgrade a dependency on Google Play Services from 9.0.2 to 9.2.0 within an Android app, namely the Locations API:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
   ...
}
```

The APIs were downloaded from the SDK Manager:

- Google Play services, rev 31
- Google Repository, rev 29

However, the code could no longer compile because a drawable resource was not found, specifically `@drawable/powered_by_google_light` (an attribution image for Google).

Checking the AAR under `sdk_location/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/9.2.0`, it seems the resource is missing. In fact, the `res` folder inside the AAR is empty. However it existed in the one of version 9.0.2.

Did anyone encounter this? I tried re-installing the repository more than once from the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 5):

Issue solved by adding the dependency on the Places API:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
   ...
}
```

It seems before that version, the Places dependency was implicitly declared.

Also related: [Google Play Services 9.2.0 missing classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068982/google-play-services-9-2-0-missing-classes)